# Can't enable a pulse sink pointing to bluetooth headset

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, bluez

<sub>My qustion might be a dup of this one:</sub>

> [Adding a pulse audio bluetooth sink configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484297/adding-a-pulse-audio-bluetooth-sink-configuration)

My situation: the device is paired, the pulse sink is created, it cannot be enabled.

**Details**:
*Pairing*:

```
vorac@msi:~$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller C0:B6:F9:77:86:6A Pairable: yes
[TRACER Powertone V2]# info
Device 64:DC:AB:AD:7F:A5 (public)
        Name: TRACER Powertone V2
        Alias: TRACER Powertone V2
        Class: 0x00340404
        Icon: audio-headset
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        WakeAllowed: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: bluetooth:v05D6p000Ad0240
[TRACER Powertone V2]#
```

*Pulse*:

```
vorac@msi:~$ pactl suspend-sink 0 false && pactl list sinks short && echo && echo
0       alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       RUNNING
1       bluez_sink.64_DC_AB_AD_7F_A5.handsfree_head_unit        module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz        SUSPENDED



vorac@msi:~$ pactl suspend-sink 0 true && pactl list sinks short && echo && echo
0       alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED
1       bluez_sink.64_DC_AB_AD_7F_A5.handsfree_head_unit        module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz        SUSPENDED



vorac@msi:~$ pactl suspend-sink 1 false && pactl list sinks short && echo && echo
0       alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED
1       bluez_sink.64_DC_AB_AD_7F_A5.handsfree_head_unit        module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz        SUSPENDED
```